# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have a word Add-in, i use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile to get the configuration file.

The result given by above API is different for .net 1.1 and .net 2.0 which is causing problems for me.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: what result do you get? and what do you expect? some examples will be helpful

Comment: My Add-in copies its files(dll's) to ProgramFiles\Microsoft office\office 12\<SomeName>.  In .net 1.1 ( the path shown for configuration file is "Program Files\microsoft office\office 12\<application name>\config.xml" but for .net 2  show the path as (Program Files\microsoft office\office 12\\config.xml".

Comment: This is by design for 2.0, there is only one .config file and it is expected to be located in the directory that contains the .exe.   The Office program, not your addin.  Don't use .config files for addins.  Find the directory in which your addin is located back with Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.  And copy files to an Office directory only with an installer, UAC stops it at any other time.

Comment: While Loading the any office application (say word). Word loads the configuration file present in C:\program file\ms office\<config file> automatically. I want it to load from different config file present in different path? How do i do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should try also

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( ConfigurationUserLevel.None ).FilePath;
```

See the response for the question [What is the difference between using AppDomain and ConfigurationManager when getting the path to a configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919544/what-is-the-difference-between-using-appdomain-and-configurationmanager-when-get).